# Mirrored simple colored material doesn't render while BGE game

Tags: materials, game-engine, mirror

It happens always! 
But only today i noticed that this is exactly because i used mirror modifier.
Why it works ok in Shift +Z, but doesnt work at all in the game?

How to fix this horror? Multitexture doesnt help, Recalculate normals doesnt help, Remove doubles doesnt help...

One screen - render Shift Z

The other - render BGE Game engine

the third - render Flip direction applied BGE (wrong view from the front of the building disappeared, but still other sides have it

Uploaded the file (without cleaning doubles or recalculatig) [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try applying scale for the object (Object mode > Ctrl+A) and then recalculating normals in Edit mode

Comment: not working :( but when i clicked Flip Direction it became better, but other sides of the building (not front) have the same wrong view then

Comment: so is it like selecting and flipping direction of model's normals the whole process? until i reach the correct render result?

Comment: Show the mesh in Edit mode in solid shading please as it looks like this is problem with normals. Make another screenshot also in Object mode with object selected and Properties panel in the viewport opened (shortcut N). If possible include the blend here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and [edit] the question with the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is problem with normals orientation.
Object is composed of multiple [non-manifold](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry) meshes. There is one selected on the screenshot below and moved away, it's a wall while as I understand windows were left in place:

[image: image 1]

In this case Blender won't distinguish what is inside and what is outside so recalculating won't work here. Best solution in the long run is to remodel. This would allow easier selecting, adding details if any etc.
Fast and dirty solution though, if time is important *and* if the building isn't going to be visible from inside or from close distance, is to flip normals manually in places where you want them to be inside. Select a face, run *Select Linked* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and flip normals inside. You can enable *Backface Culling* in the Properties shelf to see which faces require repair.

[image]